# How to pass dynamic properties/hints to EJB EntityManagerFactory injection?

Tags: jpa, ejb, cdi, jta, cmobilecom-jpa

For EJB JTA, is there a way to pass dynamic properties/hints to EntityManagerFactory injection?

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="abc")
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

The properties are only available at runtime.

For Java SE, any dynamic properties/hints can be passed to

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("abc", properties)
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  All you can do is put them intelligently into your `META-INF/persistence.xml`; they are surfaced via [`PersistenceUnitInfo#getProperties()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/spi/persistenceunitinfo#getProperties()).

It is not immediately clear to me why this restriction exists.  The method a JPA provider uses to create a *container-managed* [`EntityManagerFactory`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/entitymanagerfactory) [permits a `Map` of properties](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/spi/persistenceprovider#createContainerEntityManagerFactory(javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo,java.util.Map)) in addition to [those supplied by the `META-INF/persistence.xml`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/spi/persistenceunitinfo#getProperties()) so you would think that [`@PersistenceProperty`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/persistenceproperty) could be used with [`@PersistenceUnit`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/persistenceunit) in much the same way as [it is used with `@PersistenceContext`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/persistencecontext#properties()), but, alas, no such luck.

Comment: Is there a way to override how EntityManagerFactory is injected?

Comment: No there is not.